# sqlalchemy fails to execute session.add() in a for loop

Tags: postgresql, for-loop, flask-sqlalchemy, commit, werkzeug

I have an issue with `session.add(record)` inside a `for` loop. Here's an example of a function that is called to parse lists and add records:

```
def insert_lists(list, table, default_value=''):
    for x in list:
        record = table.query.filter_by(name=x).first()
        if record is None:
            record = table(name=x)
            if default_value != '':
                record.default_new = (x == default_value)
            db.session.add(record)
            db.session.flush()
        db.session.commit()
```

This is initiated by calling a `@staticmethod` function inside a module, e.g.:

```
class Some_table(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'some_tables'
    id = Column(UUID(as_uuid=True), primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4())
    name = Column(String(), unique=True, nullable=False, ...)
    default_new = Column(Boolean, nullable=False)
    
    @staticmethod
    def insert_data_in_some_table():
        from app.functions import insert_lists #(list, table, default_value)
        types = [
            'Generic', 'Specific', 'Unique', 'Unicorn', 'Other'
        ]
        insert_lists(types, Some_table, 'Generic')
```

These are used to populate the DB with lots of pre-packaged data. It did so without restoring to `session.flush()`. It also worked regardless of whether `session.commit()` was inside the `insert_lists()` function or at the end of the `@staticmethod` code. It was working fine and then it stopped. Obviously, I don't know what triggered the change. Now, it only picks the first element on the list, adds it into the DB, and raises `werkzeug.exceptions.Conflict: 409 Conflict: duplicate key value violates unique constraint "pk_some_tables" DETAIL:  Key (id)=(2a1c72c6-871e-46a8-ba75-119649c9e083) already exists.`

Any advice on where to look for the problem will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I can't say why it worked previously  - something must have been different, either in the code, data or both.

Comment: Thanks. All is well that ends well.

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is in the model where you declared your primary key, SQLAlchemy automatically executes any parameter under default including functions, just change:

```
uuid.uuid4()
```

by

```
uuid.uuid4
```

the official documentation is the following, in the last example:

[Python-Executed Functions](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/core/defaults.html#python-executed-functions)

Comment: Please don't answer obvious duplicates.

Comment: @snakecharmerb - do you mind offering a guess about how the model worked before? It populated thousands of rows in nested loops with the uuid.uuid4(). Your solution worked like a charm, but I am rather curious why such an inconsistency is possible.